# "Pronunciation" or "phonology"?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 8 questions using [pronunciation](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) and 2 questions using [phonology](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology).

Aren't these tags synonyms? If they are synonyms, which tag should we use?

Answer (score 5):

I agree that they are synonymous in practice. I suggest using only [pronunciation](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation), not only because it is already more common, but also because it is the less technical term, and thus probably more widely understood.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a distinction, but the tag wikis should make it clear (as seen in some other SO communities: "Don't use this tag for:"). Phonology is a science that uses special terms for sounds. A phonological answer would be of a little value to someone asking a question on pronunciation because they might not understand the terms or their symbols. A non-phonological answer might be usable, but presumably of very low quality, to a phonological question.

Situations I have in mind:

1. Is the open-mid front unrounded vowel an acceptable allophone for Esperanto's *e*? [phonology](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology)
2. [How are the letters "x", "w" and "y" pronounced?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/304/how-are-the-letters-x-w-and-y-pronounced) [pronunciation](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation)

I agree with Marcos Cramer on using [pronunciation](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) primarily, but not because they'd be synonymous, rather than because it's the one that's suitable unless the question is specifically about [phonology](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology). I think in a language discussion those are likely, too, and distinct from the former.

Comment: I could still use IPA characters to give the pronunciation, even if the question is tagged [tag:pronunciation]. They are synonyms for what concern us: We don't ask questions about phonology, but pronunciation. [tag:pronunciation] is probably a better tag for a site about languages in general.